# Как обратиться к свойству объекта внутри объекта в JS?

Tags: javascript, объекты, redux

Я использую Redux. В объекте initialState хранится массив вопросов. Я хочу в этот объект поместить свойство, в которое будет записываться длина массива вопросов. Как это правильно сделать?

```
let initialState = {
  questions: [
    { name: 'Вопрос 1'},
    { name: 'Вопрос 2'}
  ],
 totalQuestionsCount:'???'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно при помощи геттера (получится свойство только для чтения):

```js
let initialState = {
  questions: [
    { name: 'Вопрос 1'},
    { name: 'Вопрос 2'}
  ],
  get totalQuestionsCount() {
    return this.questions.length;
  },
};

console.log(initialState.totalQuestionsCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через "this" в виде метода:

```js
let initialState = {
  questions: [
    { name: 'Вопрос 1'},
    { name: 'Вопрос 2'}
  ],
  totalQuestionsCount() {
    return this.questions.length
  }
};
alert(initialState.totalQuestionsCount())
```